# GSAP TweenMax mouse animation acts weirdly on mouse events

Tags: reactjs, gsap

I'm creating a portfolio website using React and I decided to replace the default cursor with a personalized one. I used GSAP TweenMax to animate my custom mouse.

Everything works fine except for some weird cases.

At certain times, when the user clicks on an element or scrolls through a component, the mouse position animates by itself to the 0,0 position (upper left corner of the screen).

I tried console.log in the only function that animated the mouse position but It's not even fired when I click or scroll. (See gifs in the bottom for illustration of the problem)

This is the mouse function used to animate the position of the custom mouse.

```
export const handleMouseMove = (bigMouseCircle, smallMouseCircle) => e => {
    TweenMax.to(bigMouseCircle.current, 0.3, {
        x: e.pageX - 16,
        y: e.pageY - 16
    });
    TweenMax.to(smallMouseCircle.current, 0.1, {
        x: e.pageX - 4,
        y: e.pageY - 4
    });
};
```

Where its used:

*App.js*

```
(...)
useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener(
            "mousemove",
            handleMouseMove(bigMouseCircle, smallMouseCircle)
        );
(...)

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener(
                "mousemove",
                handleMouseMove(bigMouseCircle, smallMouseCircle)
            );
        };
(...)
    });
(...)
<div className="cursor">
                <div ref={bigMouseCircle} className="cursor__ball cursor__ball--big" />

                <div
                    ref={smallMouseCircle}
                    className="cursor__ball cursor__ball--small"
                />
            </div>
(...)
```

Other mousehandlers are used (mousedown, mouseup, mouseout, mouseenter, mouseover) but none are fired when the bug occurs.

GIF of the bug:

preview 1: https://i.imgur.com/YvJC3gM.gif

preview 2: https://i.imgur.com/yyd7ZrQ.gif

Live website: http://adamchami.com/

Comment: Have you tried to console.log() out the e.pageX and e.pageY that are being fed into the tweens? It sure sounds like those are the problem (either not defined or 0). If you need more GSAP-specific help, you may want to post in the dedicated forums at https://greensock.com/forums

Comment: @Jack yes, but the function isn't even fired when the bug occurs so I can't check that that way. I'll post it in their forums, didn't think of that. Thanks !

Comment: @SammySadati Did you succeed ?